# Getting For item in ( Error report - unknown command

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got following error when I ran following query but I see records inserts in the table. Can you explain what is issue in my script.

```
 For item in (
 Error report - 
Unknown Command
```

Here is  my script.

```
BEGIN 
For item in (
select distinct acc_id from Mdm_MyAccount.Plan_Info where account_n in ( 
'00646','03439','05004','05222','08057','08085','08086'
) and status ='A'
)
Loop
  Insert Into Mdm_MyAccount.InsertTable(Id, Task_Id, acc_id , Crea_User_Id, UPD_D, CREA_D)  Values 
  ( Mdm_MyAccount.Sq_insert.Nextval,1,item.acc_id ,'Me',SYSDATE,SYSDATE);

End loop;
EXCEPTION WHEN others then  ROLLBACK ;
Commit;
End;
```

Comment: while it's not directly related to your question, what you're trying to do here is an infamous slow-by-slow oracle antipattern. I'd strongly suggest rewriting your code as  a single insert-select statement: `insert into mdm_myaccont.inserttable select distinct ... from mdm_myaccount.plan_info where ... `

Comment: and don't do "when others then rollback; end" either - you'll end up silently ignoring EVERY exception. this is probably not something you really want.

Comment: Your `COMMIT` is in your exception block. Put it before `EXCEPTION`.

Comment: I don't see any syntax errors here. If the records were successfully inserted into your table, that means your PL/SQL block was successfully executed. The error is being raised by something later in your script, I suspect.

Comment: Thank you all. when DBA ran the script in UAT. He had to commit again but didnt get any error. so, I will move COMMIT before EXCEPTION.

Answer (score 0):

sql*plus don't behave properly with the `blankline` by default. But we can configure sql*plus to ignore `blanklines` using following command.

```
set sqlblanklines on
```

Execute your code block after it.

You can refer [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm) for all such useful commands.

Cheers!!

Comment: I, somehow, doubt that this is the problem. SQL*Plus cares about blank lines, that's true, but **not** if they are within a PL/SQL block (which is the case here). On the other hand, no - I have no idea what is wrong with it, too few info to compute.